# Updating Tkinter Treeview with SQLite database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, treeview

I am trying to update my treeview by using a delete function but I cannot get the information to transfer over. I have `old name` and `old phone number`, and I want to update them with `new name` and `new phone number`. I keep encountering the same issue. Here is my code below:

```
def update():
 update_opt = Toplevel()
 update_opt.title("Updating")
 # grabbing old values from table 
 old_name = StringVar(update_opt, tree1.item(tree1.focus())['values'][0])
 old_phone = StringVar(update_opt, tree1.item(tree1.focus())['values'][1])

 Phone = StringVar(update_opt)
 Name = StringVar(update_opt)

 # creating labels for new/old values
 lbl1 = Label(update_opt, text="Old Name: ").grid(row=0,column=1)
 pre_name = Entry(update_opt, textvariable=old_name,state='readonly')
 pre_name.grid(row=0,column=2)

 lbl2 = Label(update_opt, text="New name: ").grid(row=1,column=1)
 new_name = Entry(update_opt, textvariable=Name).grid(row=1,column=2)
 #New_Name = new_name.get()


 lbl3 = Label(update_opt, text="Old Phone Number: ").grid(row=2,column=1)
 pre_phonenumber = Entry(update_opt, textvariable=old_phone, state='readonly')
 pre_phonenumber.grid(row=2,column=2)

 lbl4 = Label(update_opt, text="New Phone Number: ").grid(row=3,column=1)
 new_phonenumber = Entry(update_opt, textvariable=Phone).grid(row=3,column=2)
 #New_Number = new_phonenumber.get()

 save_btn = ttk.Button(update_opt, text="Save Changes",
                      command = lambda:save_changes(new_name,old_name,
                                                    new_phonenumber,
                                                    old_phone))
 save_btn.grid(row=4,column=2,sticky=W)


 update_opt.mainloop()




def save_changes(new_name, old_name, new_phonenumber, old_phone):

    selected_item = tree1.selection()

    #gets the values associated with the selected item
    values = (tree1.item(selected_item)['values'])

    query = 'UPDATE clients SET name=?, phone=? WHERE name=? AND phone=?'
    parameters=(new_name, new_phonenumber, old_name, old_phone)
    conn = sq.connect('Clients.db')
    c3 = conn.cursor()

    c3.execute(query, (new_name, new_phonenumber, values,))
    conn.commit()
    tree1.delete(selected_item)
    edit_wind.destroy()
    display_clients()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
xception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
    File "/home/zizibaby/Desktop/SD Functions .py", line 77, in <lambda>
        old_phone))
    File "/home/zizibaby/Desktop/SD Functions .py", line 98, in save_changes
        c3.execute(query, (new_name, new_phonenumber, values,))
    sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. 
    The current statement uses 4, and there are 3 supplied.
```

I added the `tree.selection` to actually grab the value however it's not working. I tried `.get()` function but it say `NoneType` for `get()`.

Please, any help?

Comment: The error means that the SQL statement has 4 placeholders (`?`), but you supply only 3 `(new_name, new_phonenumber, values,)`.  According to your code, should you use the `parameters` variable instead?